# Should all classes and interfaces ultimately derive from one Class, and how does this affect type safety?

Tags: object-oriented, architecture, object-oriented-design, class, hierarchy

If I have "Object" as the top level class, then I have various interfaces, `ISomething, ISomethingB, ISomethingC`, then I have `Class x,y,z`, all ultimately deriving from the class Object (these subclasses don't have to derive from each other), wouldn't me having one class at the top like "Object" in .NET lead to, or possibly lead to, type safety issues like:

```
Object myText = "Johnny";
```

instead of

```
string myText = "Johnny";
```

If I used the former, does that mean I could do something like this?

```
Object myText = "Johnny";
double someValue = 0.0;
someValue = "Johnny";
```

That doesn't make sense, but is it legal?

Should there always be a main object at the type of a class hierarchy like in .NET from which all others derive?

As an example, take a school application.

Students, Staff, Classes, Grades, and so on.

Should there be a top level object like "School" and have all of those classes or interfaces below it?  I can't think of why I'd do that.  Why not have four or five top level classes that do not intersect anywhere?

Edit:  I have read, [Why all classes in .NET globally inherits from Object class?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157450/why-all-classes-in-net-globally-inherits-from-object-class)

Comment: What is it about the question you linked along with its answer that you don't feel answers your question?

Comment: Not sure what  you're going for but your snippet won't compile let alone run.  `someValue` is of type `double`, and will not be allowed an assignment to a string literal; neither will it be allowed an assignment to `myText`.

Comment: @ErikEidt Why wouldn't it compile?  I don't understand.  myText is of type Object and so is double.

Comment: @JeffO I don't know it is saying I should not do this.  It says it was because Generics were missing.  The consensus seems to indicate no, don't do this, but it was really about .NET, not all OOD.  I'll keep reading it though.

Comment: @ErikEidt It doesn't compile.  But I don't undestand why it doesn't if double is also an Object.

Comment: First, your snippet declares `myText` but doesn't use it.  Next, it assigns a string literal to a variable whose type is double.  That won't fly.  Just because they/all share a common base type `Object` doesn't mean you can do whatever you want.  You still have to follow the basic type system rules, and that means passing compile time checks, and runtime checks.

Comment: The compile time checks are done using the type information available at compile time.  The runtime checks are done using the type information available at runtime.  There is a relationship between the information available at compile time and at runtime.  Runtime always a totally accurate picture of various types of entities.  However, sometimes compile time does as well, and, when compile time doesn't have the complete picture it most often has more information than merely `Object`.  And this enables a certain amount of checking even if the information is a bit imprecise or general.

Comment: (And when the system knows that the compile time checks were performed and were sufficient, then it can omit many of the runtime checks.)

Comment: In theory should it work?

Comment: @johnny If I ask you for an apple, and you give me a pizza, I'd be confused. If you told me "Well, you asked for an apple, and an apple is food. I gave you a pizza, and pizza is food too. So what are you complaining about?" I'd still be confused. And so is the compiler

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why all classes in .NET globally inherits from Object class?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/157450/why-all-classes-in-net-globally-inherits-from-object-class)

Comment: @johnny 'double' is an 'Object', yes, but not the other way around. You declared 'someValue' as a 'double', but are trying to assign an 'object' value to it.  Maybe you meant your last line to read 'myText = someValue;' instead?